# Python os.execve()

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying spawn new process with method `execve()` from `os` module. I need spawn new process and do some stuff in another directory, but i won't change.

code:

```
import os

os.execve('/bin/ls', ['/bin/ls'], {'PATH': '/tmp'})
```

when i ran this code, i got content of directory where i'm, not from `/tmp` directory. What i'm doing wrong? I cannot use `os.chdir()` or change the way how the run command (like use module `subprocess`)

Answer (score 0):

Change your current working directory before calling `execve()`. The CWD will be inherited by the new process.

```
import os
os.chdir('/tmp')
os.execve('/bin/ls', ['arg1', 'arg2'], {'PATH': 'is_inherited_anyway'})
```

Comment: Yeah, i know this (os.chdir()) method, but if it is possible i need use only execve() method

Comment: I suspect `ls` just an example? If not, use `/tmp` as the argument... Changing `PATH` is not what you want anyhow. Otherwise, you are basically out of luck; expand your question about what it is you are actually doing

Comment: yeah, `ls` is here just an example... ok i edit code example above

Answer (score 0):

If there is `/bin/sh` on the system (which it should be) you can do:

```py
import os
target_dir = '/tmp'
your_target_command_with_args = 'ls' # Just put the arguments for the command space-separated in this string, as if this string were your system's default shell.
os.execve('/bin/sh', ['/bin/sh', '-c', f'cd "{target_dir}"; {your_target_command_with_args}'], {})
```

If it would be specifically about `/bin/ls` you could actually give that a path as an argument (some other programs also support being given a path as an argument), like this:

```py
import os
target_dir = '/tmp'
os.execve('/bin/ls', ['/bin/ls', target_dir], {})
```

I think your approach didn't work because `ls` just doesn't read the `PATH` envvar to determine what directory to list, which you set in the third argument (when I omitted that, `os.execve` complained about the argument `env` (position 3) missing).

Also, the `PATH` envvar normally contains a colon-separated list of directories in which a command is searched for, like `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`. If you enter the command `ls` in any shell it searches in each of these directories for a file called `ls` and the first one it finds is then run.